# How to get inserted PK generated on database Using EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The following code works for logging deleted entities and changed attributes.
When the entry is an insert the EntidadeId is 0 because I couldn't get it after SaveChangesAsync()

After SaveChangesAsync() all tracked entries status are changed to "Unchanged" and I can't know which entity is the inserted one.

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entitys = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted) &&
                    (e.Entity is EntidadeBase));    

    foreach (EntityEntry entrada in entitys.ToList())
    {
        if (entrada.State == EntityState.Added || entrada.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            var log = new Log();                      

            log.UsuarioId = UsuarioId;
            log.Entidade = entrada.Entity.GetType().Name;
            log.TipoOperacao = entrada.State == EntityState.Added ? TipoOperacao.Incluir : TipoOperacao.Excluir;
            log.EntidadeId = entrada.State == EntityState.Added ? "0" : ((EntidadeBase)entrada.Entity).GetId();

            Historico.Add(log);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (PropertyEntry prop in entrada.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified))
            {
                var log = new Log();
                log.TipoOperacao = TipoOperacao.Alterar;
                log.Atributo = prop.Metadata.PropertyInfo?.Name;
                log.EntidadeId = ((EntidadeBase)entrada.Entity).GetId();
                log.TipoOperacao = TipoOperacao.Alterar;
                log.ValorAntigo = prop.OriginalValue?.ToString();
                log.ValorNovo = prop.CurrentValue?.ToString();

                Historico.Add(log);
            }
        }
    }

     base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Best Regards

I'm trying to get the inserted Id after SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: The ID (PK) will be updated in your entity after you called SaveChanges (which you should await, I missed that, good spot @Flydog57!). Next time, please remove all irrelevant code and make a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also try to keep it in English as much as possible.

Comment: If you `await` the call to `SaveChangesAsync`, you should be able to pull out the new ID. 
 As an aside, why do you call `entitys.ToList()` in your `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

This code likely won't be doing what you think it will be doing:

```
        var log = new Log();
        log.TipoOperacao = TipoOperacao.Alterar;

        foreach (PropertyEntry prop in entrada.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified))
        {
            log.Atributo = prop.Metadata.PropertyInfo?.Name;
            log.Entidade = entrada.Entity.GetType().Name;
            log.EntidadeHistorico = EntidadeHistorico.Pessoa;
            log.EntidadeId = ((EntidadeBase)entrada.Entity).GetId();
            log.TipoOperacao = TipoOperacao.Alterar;
            log.ValorAntigo = prop.OriginalValue?.ToString();
            log.ValorNovo = prop.CurrentValue?.ToString();

            Historico.Add(log);
        }
```

EF works with references, so if you want a log entry for each modified property, you will need to "new" up a new log entry within the loop. The above code will just be overwriting the same log record resulting in the last modified property value being the only thing recorded.

To get the IDs for inserted records, EF will populate these in the attached entities automatically after calling `SaveChanges`. As mentioned in the comments, if you use the `async` methods you need to `await` them.

To capture the Log records and get their affected IDs, hang on to the entities and fetch the IDs after `SaveChanges`. Something like this should do the trick:

List logs = new();

var entitys = ChangeTracker.Entries()
.Where(e => (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted) &&
(e.Entity is EntidadeBase));

```
foreach (EntityEntry entrada in entitys.ToList())
{
    if (entrada.State == EntityState.Added || entrada.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        var log = new Log();          

        log.EmpresaId = 1;
        log.UsuarioId = UsuarioId;
        log.Data = DateTime.Now;
        log.Entidade = entrada.Entity.GetType().Name;
        log.EntidadeHistorico = EntidadeHistorico.Pessoa;
        log.TipoOperacao = entrada.State == EntityState.Added ? TipoOperacao.Incluir : TipoOperacao.Excluir;
        log.EntidadeId = entrada.State == EntityState.Added ? "0" : ((EntidadeBase)entrada.Entity).GetId();

        Historico.Add(log);
        logs.Add(log);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (PropertyEntry prop in entrada.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified))
        {
            var log = new Log();
            log.Atributo = prop.Metadata.PropertyInfo?.Name;
            log.Entidade = entrada.Entity.GetType().Name;
            log.EntidadeHistorico = EntidadeHistorico.Pessoa;
            log.EntidadeId = ((EntidadeBase)entrada.Entity).GetId();
            log.TipoOperacao = TipoOperacao.Alterar;
            log.ValorAntigo = prop.OriginalValue?.ToString();
            log.ValorNovo = prop.CurrentValue?.ToString();

            Historico.Add(log);
            logs.Add(log);
        }
    }
}

 await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
 // Log IDs will be populated now.
 var logIds = logs.Select(x => x.LogId).ToList();
```

}